# Trigger javascript events with a minimum interval

Tags: javascript, algorithm, events, timeout

I want to trigger an action (like an "Update saved!" message) whenever a repeated event occurs (hitting the "save" button) but not trigger it twice within a given time period.

For the following, I want excecuteFunction() to trigger at most once every 3 seconds, but if the setInterval is cleared after 4.5 seconds I would *still* want it to trigger again after 6 seconds.

```
var minimumTime = 3000; // minimum ms between events
function myTimedEvent() {
    if ( lessThanMinimumTime() )
        // loop through again
    else {
        executeFunction();
    }
}
window.setInterval(myTimedEvent, 500);
```

`executeFunction()` could create a timestamp on execution, and `lessThanMinimumTime()` could compare that timestamp to the current time, then set a sub-interval that's then cleared by `executeFunction()` if it's inside the minimum time range.

There must be a better way.

Comment: Why not just disabling the button then enabling it in timer?

Comment: The button thing was just an example - it's actually for a background process.

Comment: I'd consider wrapping the function calls in a callBack class that holds timestamps for the last call of each function... seems ugly but reliable...

Answer (score 0):

This will fire the event no more than once every three second (plus the time it takes executeFunction() to execute), but will still call executeFunction() if the event fires during the last three seconds. Is this what you're looking for?

```
var minimumTime = 3000; // minimum ms between events
var lastFired = null;
var timer;
function myEventHandler(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if(lessThanMinimumTime()){
        timer = setTimeout(myEventHandler, lastFired - now + minimumTime);
    } else {
        executeFunction();
        lastFired = now;
    }
}

function lessThanMinimumTime(){
    if(lastFired == null) return false;
    return lastFired > new Date().getTime() - minimumTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Function.prototype.restrictCallsToInterval = function(sec){
    var self = this,
        last, queued, diff;

    return function(){
        var args = arguments;
        if(last && !queued && (diff = (new Date().getTime() - last + 1000*sec)) > 0){
            // queue this up
            queued = setTimeout(function(){
                self.apply(self, args);
            }, diff);

            return;
        }

        last = new Date().getTime();
        self.apply(self, args);
    }
};

function doSomething(x){
    console.log(x);
}

doSomething = doSomething.restrictCallsToInterval(3);
doSomething(22);
doSomething(23);
```

Comment: This is the best answer - it's not simpler, but it hides all the ugliness. But...it also doesn't quite work. If you make a third call to doSomething(24) it fires that third call immediately and only cues the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you asked for "better way" - I don't think there is really any *better* way, but this is the most simple way I can think of:

```
var minimumTime = 3000; // minimum ms between events
var canFireEvent = true;
function myTimedEvent() {
    if (canFireEvent) {
        canFireEvent = false;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            canFireEvent = true;
        }, minimumTime);
        executeFunction();
    }
}
```

Using one single boolean flag. No messing with dates.

[Proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/prSP3/).
(Function executed every 3 seconds although the timer interval is 1 second)

Comment: This works for the minimum interval, but it doesn't ensure the firing of the last event: if we cut off the setInterval after 4.5 seconds, it would not fire after 6 seconds.